# Producing every string of a given length using some range of characters

Tags: java, performance, circular-list

Ever since I was a kid I wanted to understand how brute force programs work. I have not been able to make sense of any of the examples throughout the internet, so it became a personal challenge to make my own. Now that I have a couple Java classes under my belt, I realized I could tackle this problem with a linked list. Any advice about best practices, better algorithms, or how to make the existing one faster are welcome.

The problem to solve is to produce every possible combination of characters for a given range of characters and a given string length. This is purely for the purpose of personal learning.

```
public class BruteForce {

    final int minASCII = 97;
    final int maxASCII = 122;
    final int stringLength = 4;

    CharNode firstNode = new CharNode(minASCII);

    public BruteForce() {

        CharNode tempNode = firstNode;
        //Create stringLength number of CharNodes as a doubly linked list
        //The last node is used as an end of string marker
        for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
            CharNode nextNode = new CharNode(minASCII - 1);
            tempNode.setNextNode(nextNode);
            nextNode.setPreviousNode(tempNode);
            tempNode = nextNode;

            //Link the last node with the first node, and the first node with
            //the last node to make it a circular linked list
            if (i == stringLength - 1) {
                nextNode.setNextNode(firstNode);
                firstNode.setPreviousNode(nextNode);
            }
        }
        //keep printing and incrementing the nodes until the last
        //marker node is incremented
        while (firstNode.getPreviousNode().getData() == (minASCII - 1)) {
            printData();
            firstNode.incrementData();
        }
    }

    private void printData() {

        CharNode tempNode = firstNode;

        while (tempNode.getData() != (minASCII -1)){
            System.out.print((char)tempNode.getData());
            tempNode = tempNode.getNextNode();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /*
     * One CharNode represents one character. Each CharNode links to
     * the next CharNode and to the previous CharNode. Based on the
     * circular doubly linked list data structure.
     */
    private class CharNode {

        private int data = 0;
        private CharNode nextNode = null;
        private CharNode previousNode = null;

        public CharNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setData(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public int getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setNextNode(CharNode nextNode) {
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

        public CharNode getNextNode() {
            return nextNode;
        }

        //Automatically increment the next node and reset data to minASCII
        //once maxASCII is reached
        public void incrementData() {
            if (data >= maxASCII) {
                this.getNextNode().incrementData();
                data = minASCII;
            }
            else
                data++;
        }

        public CharNode getPreviousNode() {
            return previousNode;
        }

        public void setPreviousNode(CharNode previousNode) {
            this.previousNode = previousNode;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BruteForce();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t really understand what this is supposed to mean. “brute force” simply means that a solution is found by trying all potential solutions out until one is found that fits. It’s a *general principle* of problem solving rather than one specific solution for one specific problem. It’s also (almost?) always the simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is alread good. I would drop the *circular* from the list, since you don't really need it, do you?

If you care about speed more than flexibility, you can switch to using primitive data types and avoid following references, since that requires reading from RAM. Having just a simple array of ints is fast and simple.

In the following code you have the flexibility of providing `min`, `max` and `len` at runtime. If you want to have individual values of `min` and `max` for each character, you can provide them as int arrays, too.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BruteForce {

  final int min;
  final int max;
  final int stringLength;

  /**
   * One more element than <i>stringLength</i>,
   * to efficiently check for overflow.
   */
  private final int[] chars;

  public BruteForce(char min, char max, int len) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.stringLength = len;

    chars = new int[stringLength + 1];
    Arrays.fill(chars, 1, chars.length, min);
  }

  public void run() {
    while (chars[0] == 0) {
      print();
      increment();
    }
  }

  private void increment() {
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (chars[i] < max) {
        chars[i]++;
        return;
      }
      chars[i] = min;
    }
  }

  private void print() {
    for (int i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
      System.out.print((char) chars[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BruteForce('a', 'z', 4).run();
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice, I like your code. Good point about the circular nature of my linked list. I can take out `nextNode.setNextNode(firstNode);` since its not being used. Setting the first node's previous node on the other hand is a quick way to check if I need to stop incrementing (not sure how else I could do it). I think you might be right about my use of objects in heap RAM possibly slowing it down. I think yours uses object too though. Since your primitive array of chars was created with the "new" keyword, they will also be allocated on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: In Java it is not possible to allocate non-primitive types on the stack. So I had to use the `new` operator once. My point is that the data that is modified is packed closely together, so that it doesn't take away much of the memory cache.

Comment: Ah ok I forgot about that. So this might be faster in c or c++  because we can allocate an array of size stringLength on the stack. Also good point about the char array being close together. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to switch to C++ in this case. Nor is it in many other cases. The array gets allocated once and for all, only when the `BruteForce` object is created. It's definitely possible to write Java code that does very little memory allocation. And the Java compiler usually creates code that is equally fast as in C or C++, or even a little faster, since it is first profiled before compiling; and you get the extra safety. (No *undefined behavior*, which I see as a great relief.)

Answer (score 4):

There is not much to understand about "brute forcing" something. "Brute force" does not mean a particular algorithm.

"Brute force" simply means that instead of using a clever algorithm to simplify a problem (simplify here means reducing the running time) you just test every single possible input to see which one produces the right result.

For example in password cracking, "brute force" means calculating every single possible password and testing them one by one. A smart algorithm would try passwords that are based on names and such first, because we know those are used way too often.

So, first of all, you need to clarify the problem that you are trying to solve through brute force.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated my question to be more clear. This was just to satisfy my personal curiosity about how other password brute force algorithms might work better than mine. I'm not interested in dictionary attacks even though it would be better suited for a cracking job.